# How to change heading of group column from "Group" to "my custom heading"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

[I want to change the heading "Group" to "MyCustomHeading" I am using treeData in  from material ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAOrP.png)

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: hard to give an answer without more detail but if you go to the documentation 
https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/tree-data/
the last example might be what you are looking for how about restructure your code that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use
`renderHeader=()=><div>Your Header</div>`
you need to return the html element to render however you want it to look like.